# FFMPEG: Smooth streaming on IOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, video, ffmpeg, mp4

I am transcoding a file to the ISMV "smooth streaming" format to create fragmented MP4 files.

The Ffmpeg parameters I use are the following:

```
ffmpeg -i "'+inputUrl+'" -g 52 -threads 0 \
-vcodec libx264 -coder 0 -flags -loop -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-crf 22 -subq 0 -sc_threshold 0 -s 1280x720 -profile:v baseline \
-keyint_min 150 -deinterlace -maxrate 10000000 -bufsize 10000000 \
-b 1200k -acodec aac -ar 48000 -ab 192k -strict experimental \
-movflags +frag_keyframe+empty_moov '+outputUrl
```

The main purpose is to play the file while transcoding. 
This works great on my desktop. Sadly though, this can not be said for Android and IOS devices. It simply does not play anything.

Is it possible to play a fragmented mp4 on these devices?